# Is the sum of this two Normal a Normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let us take $X_1$ standard Gaussian and a R.V. $Z$ with $P(Z=1)=0.5$ and $P(Z=-1)=0.5$. Set $X_2 = ZX_1$. So we can verify that $X_2 ∼ N(0,1)$. Now, the question is: is $Y = X_1 +X_2$ normal?

Here is my attempt:

$P(Y \leq y)= P(X_1+ZX_1 \leq y)= P(Z(2X_1) \leq
 y|Z=1)P(Z=1)+P(Z(2X_1) \leq y|Z=-1)P(Z=-1)=P(2X_1 \leq y)0.5+P(-2X_1
\leq y)0.5$

I am stuck here. Can I claim that because the normal is symmetric,
 then $P(-2X_1 \leq y) = P(-2X_1 \leq y)=P(2X_1 \leq y)$, so that $P(Y \leq y)=P(2X_1 \leq y)$, which is the cdf of a normal?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik In this question OP is not adding independent normal random variables.

Comment: Indeed, it is clear that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kabo Murphy and J.G. 's answers are both correct. For completeness I will also prove that $Y = X_1 + X_2$ is not normal using my initial attempt.

$P(Y \leq y)= P(X_1+ZX_1 \leq y)= P(X_1(1+Z) \leq
 y|Z=1)P(Z=1)+P(X_1(1+Z) \leq y|Z=-1)P(Z=-1)=P(2X_1 \leq y)0.5+P(
 y \geq 0)0.5=0.5\Phi(y/2)+0.5I_{y\geq0}(y)$ which is clearly not a normal Cdf

Answer (score 2):

Since $1+Z$ is either $0$ or $2$, each with probability $\frac12$, so $X(1+Z)$ has probability $\frac12$ of being $0$. Therefore, it isn't Normal.

For what it's worth, many sources would say $Z$ has a [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution), not a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution).

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I edited my post. Could you please tell me what is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: @Alchemy Your $P(Z=-1)$ term contains your first error.

Answer (score 1):

The question  has been  edited. I am assuming  here that $Z$ take s values $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ each.

The first statement itself is false without independence. So assume that $Z$ and $X_1$ are independent so that $X_2$ is normal.

The characteristic function of $Y$ is easily calculated by conditioning on $Z$. We get $Ee^{-t^{2}(1+Z)^{2}/2}$ which is $\frac 1 2 e^{-t^{2}/2}+\frac 1 2 e^{-2t^{2}}$. This is not a normal characteristic function so the answer is NO, $Y$ is not normally distributed.

EDIT. In the modified version also it is not true that the sum is normal. The mistake in your attempt is in thinking that $X_1+ZX_1$ is either $2X_1$ or $-2X_1$. It is  either $0$ or $2X_1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but without using characteristic functions, how do I show that Y is not normal? What is wrong with my computations? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: In standard terminology Bernoulli random variables take values $0$ and $1$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each, right? You are taking the values as $-1$ and $+1$. @Alchemy    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution

Comment: Yes, in my example I am assuming that Z takes either 1 or -1 with equal probability, so I will not name it a bernoulli anymore, sorry for the confusion. I will edit my post.

Comment: @Alchemy Check your calculation of $P(Y \leq y)$. You made mistakes. $(1+Z)X_1$ is either $0$ or $2X_1$. You are taking at as $2X_1$ or $-2X_1$.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.